# How To use Angular Material with Foundation-apps

Tags: angular-material, zurb-foundation-apps

i have problem , i want to use **Angular Material** With **Foundation For Apps**
so i have installed Foundation for apps With Command Line using this ...

```
foundation-apps new project
```

and then install angular material after `cd project`:

```
bower install angular-material
```

then i see this picture :

i choose the 2nd option ... To install material ...

After This i used `package.json` to use the files of material ,, 
so this is my problem 
and:

- How Use Angular material with foundation ... i want foundation-apps Grid and some features and the Material features ....

is this the Right Way !!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIu40.png

Comment: Am working on similar implementation, am now trying to understand how material design works, the documentation is pretty thin. Am just not sure if it offers its own grid and if foundation class can be applied to material directives/tags using https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs and https://material.angular.io/. Still expirementing